# I'm having trouble getting my local notification to show up at the set time on xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification, simulator

I'm fairly new to coding and was wondering how to do this or if my code was the problem. I initially had it set to go off ten seconds after notifications were accepted by the simulator but the actual notification would not go off there either.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
          { (granted, error) in

      }
      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = "Prevent nosocomial infections!"
      content.body = "Make sure to do hand hygiene"
      content.sound = .default

      var dateComponents = DateComponents ()
      dateComponents.hour = 9
      dateComponents.minute = 30

      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
      let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

      center.add(request) { (error) in
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question for clarification, because of how you've worded things - does this code work on an actual device?

Comment: No it didn't work on either.

Answer (score 0):

> I initially had it set to go off ten seconds after notifications were accepted by the simulator

No, that's not what you're doing. `center.requestAuthorization` returns its value asynchronously. So you are trying to schedule the notification *before* the user has accepted the notifications: the dialog is still up, asking about the notifications, and meanwhile you just go directly on with your code. Obviously that's not going to work, because notifications have not yet been accepted. You need to move that code *into* the (currently empty) completion handler for `requestAuthorization`.